# Issue with Concurrent Access of a Queue (Multiple Producers and Consumers) - C++, Boost

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, producer-consumer

I'm writing an application which has an event queue. My intention is to create this in such a way that multiple threads can write and one thread can read from the queue, and hand over the processing of a popped element to another thread so that the subsequent pop again will not be blocked. I used a lock and a condition variable for pushing and popping items from the queue:

```
void Publisher::popEvent(boost::shared_ptr<Event>& event) {

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
    while(eventQueue.empty())
    {
        queueConditionVariable.wait(lock);
    }
    event = eventQueue.front();
    eventQueue.pop();
    lock.unlock(); 
}

void Publisher::pushEvent(boost::shared_ptr<Event> event) {

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
    eventQueue.push(event);
    lock.unlock();
    queueConditionVariable.notify_one();

}
```

In the constructor of the Publisher class (only one instance is created), I'm starting one thread which will iterate through a loop till a notify_one() is captured, and then is starting up another thread to process the event popped from the queue:

In constructor:

```
publishthreadGroup = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread_group> (new boost::thread_group());
publishthreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(queueProcessor, this));
```

queueProcessor method:

```
void queueProcessor(Publisher* agent) {

while(true) {
    boost::shared_ptr<Event> event;
    agent->getEvent(event);
    agent->publishthreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(dispatcher, agent, event));

    }
}
```

and in the dispatcher method, the relevant processing is done and the processed information is published to a server via thrift. In another method called before program exists, which is in the main thread, I call join_all() so that main thread waits till threads are done.

In this implementation, after the thread for dispatcher is made, in the while loop above, I have experienced a deadlock/hang. The running code seem to be stuck. What is the issue in this implementation? And is there a much cleaner, better way of doing what I am trying to do? (Multiple producers and one one consumer thread iterating through the queue and handing off the processing of an element to a different thread)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the complete example?

Comment: I assume that in your `queueProcessor` method you meant to call `agent->popEvent(event)` rather than `agent->getEvent(event)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `queueProcessor` function will run forever and the thread running it will never exit.  Any threads created by that function will do their work and exit, but this thread - the first one created in the `publishthreadGroup` - has a `while(true)` loop that has no way of stopping.  Thus a call to `join_all()` will wait forever.  Can you create some other flag variable that triggers that function to exit the loop and return?  That should do the trick!